# MySQL indexes not used on LIKE for INT?

Tags: mysql, sql, select, indexing

I don't know if this is a bug or a feature, or if I'm doing something wrong. I have inherited a MySQL database with a few hundred thousand rows. This table includes the fields 'full_name' which is a VARCHAR, and 'workpack' which is an INT.

One thing this table is used for is providing an autocomplete feature when people start filling in an HTML form, and this is offered on the above fields. I noticed that when typing in a 'full_name' the autocomplete appears and updates very quickly but when typing in an integer for 'workpack' the autocomplete is slow to appear and update, to the point of being almost unusable.

Both these fields are indexed, a simplified example of the query structure is below:

```
SELECT distinct full_name       
FROM xx.xx
WHERE full_name LIKE 'Joe Bl%';
```

An EXPLAIN suggests this is using the index 'full_name' as expected.

An almost identical query for the 'workpack':

```
SELECT distinct workpack
FROM xx.xx
WHERE workpack LIKE '153%';
```

An EXPLAIN here shows it is not using the index 'workpack', even when I use FORCE INDEX.

Because the only difference I can see is that one is an INT and one a VARCHAR, I decided to experiment by creating a local copy of the table and changing the datatype of 'workpack' to VARCHAR. It worked! Perhaps not that surprising to some, but I want to know why this happens. Obviously my 'workpack' data should be stored as INT because that's what it is, but to have my autocomplete function work in a reasonable way it seems like I need to change it to VARCHAR. I realise LIKE is a string function, but is there a logical, technical reason for it to fail to use the index just because it's an INT, given that the LIKE function still works on INT?

Comment: When you apply LIKE against an INT column there's an implicit typecast to a VarChar (which prevents index usage in all DBMSes). And `LIKE '153%` indicates you don't have a numeric value, but a string of digits (like a *phone number*).

Comment: if `workpack` is never meant to be used in mathematical operations, there is no reason not to change it to `VARCHAR` in your database even if it looks like number. If it is used for maths, you can trade data volume with speed by adding a duplicate column with `VARCHAR` type

Comment: There's a perfectly valid logical, technical reason for it to fail to use the index, your conclusion is a fallacy. Strings are numbers. Each "letter" allocates 1 - 4 bytes, depending on encoding used. It's a number, internally. When you index some text, a *sequence of numbers* is stored in an ordered data structure. When you index an integer, a *number* (one number, that is `1 - 8` bytes long) is stored in an ordered data structure. So, there you have it - you told MySQL to break this one number that's `1 - 8` bytes into a sequence of numbers that aren't anywhere to be found in the index.

Answer (score 2):

The index is not suitable here because you are casting it to a string. And if your sort a list of number with their value or with their string representation, the result will be different. Take for exemple 125 and 1234. When sorting by value, you get this :

- 125
- 1234

And when sorting by string representation you get this :

- 1234
- 125

So the index is useless in your case because it is in the value order(since you field is an int) while your search would require the string order(because you are using `like` to find some string prefix). (Keep in mind that an index is really just a sorted list)

Answer (score 1):

An index is essentially a sorted data structure that maps from the **value** of a column to the row that contains it. Therefore, it can only be used when your query uses the actual value, not some transformation on it (such as converting the `int` to a `varchar`).

One neat solution for such issues (available since MySQL 5.7.6) is to add an auto generated column for the sole purpose of indexing it and using it in such queries. It may waste some space (since you hold two copies of the same data - the original data and the calculated column), but if your application heavily uses this query, it may be worth it:

```
CREATE TABLE xx.xx (
    full_name VARCHAR(100),
    workpack INT,
    workpack_str CHAR(20) AS CAST(workpack AS CHAR) STORED, 
    INDEX(full_name),
    INDEX workpack_str 
)
```